# My timer in VB.NET is Losing one second 

Tags: vb.net, time, timer

I use a DateTimePicker to pick a dateTime value and see how much time I have until it is zero:

```
Private Sub Timer1_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick

timeInSeconds = (DateTimePicker1.Value.Subtract(System.DateTime.Now)).ToString
                'RichTextBox1.Text = RichTextBox1.Text + vbTab + timeInSeconds.ToString
                timeInSeconds = timeInSeconds.Substring(0, timeInSeconds.LastIndexOf("."))

End Sub
```

The RichTextbox above shows that I loose a second at about each 30 seconds:

```
23:59:47.4060217
23:59:46.3939638
23:59:45.3799058
23:59:44.3648477
23:59:43.3517898
23:59:42.3377318
23:59:41.3236738
23:59:40.3096158
23:59:39.2955578
23:59:38.2814998
23:59:37.2674418
23:59:36.2533838
23:59:35.2393258
23:59:34.2242677
23:59:33.2112098
23:59:32.1981518
23:59:31.1830938
23:59:30.1690358
23:59:29.1549778
23:59:28.1409198
23:59:27.1268618
23:59:26.1128038
23:59:25.0997458
23:59:24.0856878
23:59:23.0716298
23:59:22.0575718
23:59:21.0435138
23:59:20.0284558
23:59:19.0143978
**23:59:18.0013398
23:59:16.9872818**
```

so using

```
timeInSeconds = timeInSeconds.Substring(0, timeInSeconds.LastIndexOf("."))
```

it goes from 23:59:18 to 23:59:16

Why is that so? What I do wrong?
Is it the time that

```
(DateTimePicker1.Value.Subtract(System.DateTime.Now)).ToString
```

takes place that I am loosing?

*The timer is set to make changes each one second.*

What Can I do to have the right results?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The timer does not have a resolution of 1 second. You are not guaranteed that kind of precision.

Comment: And if you take the decimals in your calculation, the difference between each step is almost the same: 1.013... seconds, which will explain the leap from 18.001... to 16.987...

Comment: Hmm, 23:59:18.0013398 - 23:59:16.9872818 is a second.  Make the timer tick at less than a second if you want a better guarantee to see all digits.

Comment: @Hans Passant, If I change the timer tick at less than a second (for example 250 ms) it changes from, say, 23:58:28 to 23:58:27 in less than a second, I've tried that,too.

Comment: Well, sure, your measurement error will always be larger than your sample rate.  So a visible second can take as little as 750 msec and more than 1.250 sec.  Decrease the timer interval until you no longer care about it.  Around 50 msec is no longer visible to the human eye.  Using 45 msec is a happy number since it jives well with the clock update rate (1/64 second).

Comment: I will call this an example of [Uncertainty Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uncertainty_principle)

Answer (score 0):

Try not appending the text directly, but rather concatenate the result in a tmp string.
After that assign tmp to textbox1.text.

I've been in a situations where I must modify a textbox every forloop iteration to display one byte in hex, the result was impressive when I shift to the previous methodology.

Give it a try.

From comment:

```
Private Sub Timer1_Tick(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
  Dim timeInSeconds = (DateTimePicker1.Value.Subtract(System.DateTime.Now)).ToString 
  'RichTextBox1.Text = RichTextBox1.Text + vbTab + timeInSeconds.ToString
  timeInSeconds = timeInSeconds.Substring(0, timeInSeconds.LastIndexOf("."))
  TextBox1.Text &= timeInSeconds & vbNewLine
End Sub
```

I tested this code in a 1000 milisec timer and there's no problem.

Comment: Do you mean something like that in code: timeInSeconds = timeInSeconds.Substring(0, timeInSeconds.LastIndexOf("."))
                    Dim tmp As String = timeInSeconds
                    TextBox5.Text = tmp  ?

Comment: its not exactly, when the timer stops assign the tmp string to textbox1.text (tmp must be global)

Comment: I want the correct results before timer stops. Can you show more details using code that I used in the question above? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Private Sub Timer1_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
        Dim timeInSeconds = (DateTimePicker1.Value.Subtract(System.DateTime.Now)).ToString
        'RichTextBox1.Text = RichTextBox1.Text + vbTab + timeInSeconds.ToString
        timeInSeconds = timeInSeconds.Substring(0, timeInSeconds.LastIndexOf("."))
        TextBox1.Text &= timeInSeconds & vbNewLine
    End Sub
i tested this code in a 1000 milisec timer and there's no problem ??

Comment: Please add code to your answer by editing it.  Putting that much code in comments is not fun to look at.

Answer (score 0):

The accuracy changes based on what you are doing and everything else that is going on at the same time.  You can correct for it by resetting the interval every time.  Now this breaks down when the task you are doing is longer than a second, but it will keep the ticks happening as close to the second as possible.

```
   Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
     Timer1.Enabled = False

     'do your stuff here

     Timer1.Interval = 1000 - Date.Now.Millisecond
     Timer1.Enabled = True

  End Sub
```

I typically use this technique when I want something to happen every minute or every hour on the hour.

Comment: I've tried it and it shows these wrong results: 23:58:39.9951079; 23:58:38.9990509; 23:58:38.0049941; 23:58:38.9990509

Comment: My guess is you didn't disable the timer on entering the Tick event.

Comment: @ Robert Beaubien: you are right, I did not disable the timer on entering the Tick event, but I did so and the results were worse: 23:59:41.9921606;
23:59:40.9931035;
23:59:40.0010467 Do I still write something wrong on the editor? Thanks for your interest!

Comment: with the code above, there is no way the milliseconds should ever be .99xxx anything unless what you are doing is taking a long time.  When I run it updating the text in a textbox, all the milliseconds are between .001 and .020.  ONe thing to remember is string appending gets slower and slower as you go along.  every time you edit it the old value goes to GC.  This may be affecting your values.