# StopWatch Loop using VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, time, stopwatch

I want to create a simple timer with this interface using VB.NET

[image]

I want to press Button1 and to start counting seconds in the textbox.

[I do not want to use the Timer Component because it does not offer high resolution.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10470276/my-timer-in-vb-net-is-losing-one-second)

So, I decided to use a stopWatch Class due to its high resolution according to specifications.

But according to my VB.NET code below it seems to me that the whole "dotnet adventure" is impossible. That is because when I press Button1 the whole form it freezes and I cannot press Button2 to stop the timer.

Is there anything wrong with my code?
What should I do to have the functionality described above?

Thanks in advance!

```
 
Public Class Form1
```

`Private enableTime As TimeSpan
Private stopWatch As New Stopwatch()

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    stopWatch.Start()
    If stopWatch.IsHighResolution Then
        Do
            If stopWatch.ElapsedTicks.Equals(TimeSpan.TicksPerSecond) Then
                enableTime = enableTime + TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1)
                TextBox1.Text = enableTime.ToString
                stopWatch.Restart()
            End If
            If Not stopWatch.IsRunning Then
                Exit Do
            End If
        Loop
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    stopWatch.Stop()
    stopWatch.Reset()
End Sub`

End Class

Comment: You still aren't going to get the resolution you want, even if you could figure out threading and UI updates. See how you are checking `stopWatch.ElapsedTicks.Equals(TimeSpan.TicksPerSecond)`? That might never be true. While your loop is running those ticks will slide out from under you-- you won't see them all. And even if you did, you will lose more resolution as you restart the timer. Drift is inevitable. This isn't a problem with .NET, it's a basic feature of computers (at least the ones you're using).

Comment: In my own point of view the resolution that I miss with the main concept above is a tiny number of nanoseconds so the resolution is as good as possible. But I admit the fact that I might be wrong!

Comment: What is the point of the resolution you want? Is it just so you don't 'miss' a second, like the person did in the linked question? Or do you actually need a bunch of decimal places?

Comment: I want it to be a commercial project so it must have the best resolution possible.

Comment: Is it acceptable for your commercial product to peg the CPU? Even with the background thread, your solution will always be running, which means the processor will never get a rest (and battery life will suffer, if applicable). Maybe it's OK in this scenario, but just want to make sure you are aware of it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In WinForms, there is one UI thread executing the message loop.  Basically, every event is added to the message queue, which is processed, one event after another.  When `Button1` is clicked, the `Button1_Click` method is executed and no other event will be processed until it finishes.  Since your design requires `Button2.Click` to be processed in order to terminate the loop in `Button1.Click`, it will never terminate.

To correctly implement what you want, you'd have to start the stopwatch on `Button1.Click` and put the UI update logic into the `Tick` event of a timer which you place on the form.

Comment: +1 Nice answer.  Concise yet accurate and informative.  I couldn't have put it so well.

Comment: @Andreas Is it possible to create a new thread that copes up with the functionality desired? I prefer to start learning how to use threads with .NET than having to use Timer Class!

Comment: Of course it is possible, but it does not make any sense in this case.  In fact, there is nothing a thread could actually do here.  Maybe you thought that the thread could handle the UI updates, but that is not allowed, for only the UI thread can make UI updates.  If you do UI updates in another thread, you have to use Invoke on the Form Object, which really just pushes the update to the message queue of the UI thread (exactly what the timer does).  @StevenDoggart thanks, somebody else obviously didn't like my answer :)

Comment: @Andreas is it possible to illustrate your own point of view with code so as to capture better your advice? What piece of the above functionality the Timer would embrace? Thanks in advance!

Comment: You'd have to change your code so that `Button1_Click` only contains `stopWatch.Start()` and `Timer_Tick` contains the block `If stopWatch.ElapsedTicks.Equals .... End If`.  That's it.

Comment: Anything with Equals will be subject to the missed tick problem I mentioned in my comment

Comment: @DominicP the Equals I believe that it is not the problem because with some minor changes it works well when you press button1 multiple times!

Comment: @Novemberland: You keep stating your objection to using `Timer`, but without any good reason for doing so. If your only objection is the linked question, then I think it's misplaced. If you only care about how accurate the actual timing is, then using `Stopwatch` to measure and `Timer` to update is fine.

Comment: @Novemberland Better to use >= in any case. What if the OS pre-empts your thread and delays you?

Comment: Dear Skeet, it is true that I have not stated a good reason yet for blaming Timer but this is because nobody asked me yet. I do so because using a Timer I loose 24-27 seconds regularly out of 5 minutes. It can not stand as a commercial application, I believe. It would be rejected from the users!

Comment: You'll only lose time like that if you keep time by counting the total timer ticks.  If, rather, you only use the timer as a means of updating the UI, but use the stopwatch to actually calculate the total duration, you will not lose time.

Answer (score 5):

You are "losing" time because you're manually adding to a timespan: `enableTime = enableTime + TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1)`.  The Stopwatch() itself is always accurate when you use its `Stopwatch.Elapsed` property.  All you need to do is update the GUI from a `Timer.Tick` event.  Basically the Timer just asks the Stopwatch what the current time is and displays it...no calculations needed.

The following will update ten times a second, will not "drift", and will not peg the CPU:

```
Public Class Form1

    Private SW As New Stopwatch
    Private WithEvents Tmr As New System.Windows.Forms.Timer

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Tmr.Interval = 100
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        SW.Start()
        Tmr.Start()
    End Sub

    Private Sub Tmr_Tick(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Tmr.Tick
        TextBox1.Text = SW.Elapsed.ToString
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
        SW.Stop()
        Tmr.Stop()
        SW.Reset()
    End Sub

End Class
```

Answer (score 1):

An experiment that shows that the timer should not be used for timing.  It is good to use the timer to show the stopwatch elapsed time on a periodic basis.

```
Public Class Form1
    Private stpw As New Stopwatch
    Private WithEvents aTimer As New System.Windows.Forms.Timer

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        aTimer.Interval = 100 'ten times per second
        aTimer.Start() 'start the timer
    End Sub

    Private Sub timeTick(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles aTimer.Tick
        If stpw.IsRunning Then
            'show that using the timer tick is not accurate for timing
            'add the number of ms. to the timespan
            'if the tick occurs exactly on the interval this will be accurate

            elapsedTM = elapsedTM.Add(New TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 0, aTimer.Interval))

            'show the two elapsed times
            'as of .Net 4.0 format elapsed
            TextBox1.Text = stpw.Elapsed.ToString("hh\:mm\:ss\.f")
            TextBox2.Text = elapsedTM.ToString("hh\:mm\:ss\.f")

            'show the time according to the system
            TextBox3.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString("hh:mm:ss.f")
            'show the time by adding the start time and the stopwatch elapsed time
            TextBox4.Text = strt.AddMilliseconds(stpw.ElapsedMilliseconds).ToString("hh:mm:ss.f")
        End If
    End Sub

    Dim strt As DateTime
    Dim elapsedTM As TimeSpan

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        'start
        If Not stpw.IsRunning Then
            elapsedTM = New TimeSpan(0L)
            'record the start time
            strt = DateTime.Now
            stpw.Start() 'start the stopwatch
            Button2.Select()
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
        'stop
        stpw.Stop()
        stpw.Reset()
        Button1.Select()
    End Sub
End Class
```